# Refactoring code to implement clean code using repositories

Tags: c#, asp.net, repository, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I've been refactoring code today, try to implement a clean code setup using repositories. Is this on track? Can any improvements be made?

```
public class IndexModel : PageModel
{
    private readonly MembershipFormRepository _membershipFormRepository;
    private readonly IMembershipFormViewModelService _membershipFormViewModelService;

    public IndexModel(IMembershipFormViewModelService membershipFormViewModelService, MembershipFormRepository membershipFormRepository)
    {
        _membershipFormViewModelService = membershipFormViewModelService;
        _membershipFormRepository = membershipFormRepository;
    }

    [BindProperty]
    public MembershipFormViewModel MembershipFormModel { get; set; } = new MembershipFormViewModel();

    public async Task OnGetAsync()
    {
        MembershipFormModel = await _membershipFormViewModelService.GetViewModel();
    }

    public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAddMemberAsync()
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return Page();
        }

        await _membershipFormRepository.AddMember(MembershipFormModel);

        return RedirectToPage("Index");
    }
}
```

MembershipFormViewModelService

```
public class MembershipFormViewModelService : IMembershipFormViewModelService
{
    private readonly MembershipContext _context;
    private readonly MembershipFormRepository _membershipFormRepository;


    public MembershipFormViewModelService(MembershipContext context, MembershipFormRepository membershipFormRepository)
    {
        _context = context;
        _membershipFormRepository = membershipFormRepository;
    }

    public async Task<MembershipFormViewModel> GetViewModel()
    {
        var viewModel = new MembershipFormViewModel()
            {
                Titles = await SetTitlesDropDown(),
            };

        return viewModel;
    }

    private async Task<IEnumerable<SelectListItem>> SetTitlesDropDown()
    {
        var titlesList = new List<SelectListItem>();

        var titles = await _membershipFormRepository.GetTitles();

        titlesList.AddRange(titles.Select(title => new SelectListItem() {
            Value = title.TitleId.ToString(),
            Text = title.Title
        }));

        return titlesList;
    }
}
```

IMembershipFormViewModelService

```
public interface IMembershipFormViewModelService
{
    Task<MembershipFormViewModel> GetViewModel();
}
```

MembershipFormRepository

```
public class MembershipFormRepository : IMembershipFormRepository
{
    private readonly MembershipContext _context;
    private readonly IMapper _mapper;

    public MembershipFormRepository(MembershipContext context, IMapper mapper)
    {
        _context = context;
        _mapper = mapper;
    }

    public async Task<IEnumerable<Title>> GetTitles()
    {
        return await _context.Title.ToListAsync();
    }

    public async Task AddMember(MembershipFormViewModel membershipForm)
    {
        var membership = new Membership(); 

        membership = _mapper.Map(membershipForm, membership);

        _context.Membership.Add(membership);

        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
    }
}
```

IMembershipFormRepository

```
public interface IMembershipFormRepository
{
    Task<IEnumerable<Title>> GetTitles();
    Task AddMember(MembershipFormViewModel membershipForm);
}
```

Comment: Welcome to code review. The title should reflect what the code is used for, rather than what you are trying to achieve. Know what the code does helps us give a better review.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are close. The only thing that jumps out at me is your use of the `MembershipFormRepository` type instead of the `IMembershipFormRepository` interface. This prevents you from being able to test consumers of it easily. For example, consider this case:

You have an object of type `Foo` that takes an injected instance of type `Bar` that takes an injected instance of a DB context `context`. You want to test that something on the `Foo` type works. Here is your test setup:

```
var dbContext = new Moq<DbContext>();
dbContext
    .Setup(s => s.Get())
    .Returns(new List<Item>());

var bar = new Bar(dbContext.Object);
var foo = new Foo(bar);

// assert foo.DoSomething()
```

Notice how you have to mock up a full `Bar` object, and even more troublesome, rely on `Bar` working correctly, for the test to pass. If `Bar` has a bug, your test can fail; this test, because it tests `Foo`, should only fail if `Foo` has a bug. If you injected a type of `IBar` into the `Foo` instead, you could mock that, instead of the DB context:

```
var bar = new Moq<IBar>();
bar.Setup(s => s.GetItems())
   .Returns(new List<Item>());

var foo = new Foo(bar.Object);

// assert foo.DoSomething()
```

Now, instead of relying on `Bar.GetItems` not being buggy, you just create a mocked object that always returns the same data. This test also won't fail if `Bar` changes. The first test would fail if you changed `Bar.GetItems` to call `DbContext.Where` instead of `DbContext.Get` because you hadn't mocked the `Where` call, which would once again falsely report a bug in the `Foo` type because the `Bar` type had changed or was buggy.

Comment: That makes sense, thank you. I've changed the repository registration in StartUp and changed the references to use the injected instance instead, so other than that, looks good?

Comment: Yes, it looks good. Although, this is a simple enough app there aren't too many places to make mistakes.

Comment: Yeah fair enough, I'm going to be doing the rest of the application too so it's good to know I'm on the right track at least. Thanks for the input.